# How to: Use data attribute for conditional validation

Tags: jquery, attributes, jquery-validate

Using jQuery Validate, I am doing a conditional validation on a `select` and a `text` field: the text field (`#specialization`) must be filled if a particular option (`<option value="doctor">`) was choosen from the select field (`#job`)

So far so good, here is a working copy: https://jsfiddle.net/vzx9paxz/2/

Now, I don't like to mess with too much JS code and I'd like to take advantage of the `data-rule-required` attribute. So, I'd like to evaluate the expression  `($('#job').val() === 'doctor')` directly in the HTML code, removing it from the Javascript: if it returns `true`, the `#specialization` field must be filled, otherwise it can be empty

Something like this:

```
<input type="text" data-rule-required="return ($('#job').val() === 'doctor')" class="form-control" id="specialization" name="specialization">
```

Of course this code doesn't work: I tried other expressions, like `javascript:return ($('#job').val() === 'doctor')` but with no luck at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to: Use data attribute for conditional validation

**You can't.**

---

```
data-rule-required="return ($('#job').val() === 'doctor')"
```

Even if you could execute JavaScript inside of a `data` attribute, which you can't, **[the jQuery Validate plugin cannot interpret it](https://jsfiddle.net/xyv97w8z/)** (see the JS errors in the console).  Normally, it would be looking for a `true` or `false` string within `data-rule-required`... but it cannot execute a conditional expression.

In other words, no matter what you put as a value for `data-rule-required`, the jQuery Validate plugin will interpret it as a string and choke on anything other than `"true"` or `"false"`.

Comment: Thanks, got it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Data attribute cant trigger event.
Better write a javascript function and call it with a click, focus, resize, mouseup...event. Like:

```
 <input class="user" name="">

 <script>
  $(".user").focus(function(){
 if($(this).val()=="doctor"){
 // do what ever
  }
  });
```

Comment: You're right about the data attribute.  However, the OP does not need to write an event handler, because the conditional can be placed within the plugin's `.validate()` method.

Answer (score 0):

What OP asks is not possible in general. However in some simple cases, conditional validation is possible using exclusively data attributes.  Here's an example:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <label for="password">Set new password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
    <br>
    <label for="password-confirm">Confirm password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password-confirm"
        data-rule-equalto="#password"
        data-rule-required="#password:filled">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

See it live: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a9zh2qt4/)

It will not require either password fields, unless the first field is non-blank, then the second field will be required.  This works thanks to the [extra selectors provided by jQuery Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/?s=selector).

Other useful selectors: `:checked`, `:unchecked`, `:blank`.